# AngularJs Disable Submit Button Until A File Upload Path Selected

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and I can seem to find a solution to my problem.  I have a file upload field on my site and a submit button.  This page has a drop down list and a disabled submit button when the user first hits the page.  The submit button is only enable once a selection is made from the drop down list.  This works great but I have now been asked to add a file upload option to the list which I have done and my file upload `<input type="file">` field is displayed when selected.

The issue I have is that when the user selects the upload option it's enabling my button and I only want the submit button to be enabled once the file path has been selected.

At the moment the enabling/disabling of the button is done in my view as shown below.

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <select name="selectedbankaccountname" ng-options="choice for choice in bankaccountnames" ng-model="selectedbankaccountname" class="form-control" style="width:100% !important" focus-on="setfocus" required>
                        <option></option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <!-- TODO - BUTTON NEEDS TO BE DISABLED IF BANK UPLOAD SELECTED & FILE NOT SELECTED -->
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="startautoreconciliation.selectedbankaccountname.$invalid || disablebutton" ng-click="startrec()" title="Click to start the auto reconciliation procedure.">Start Auto Rec</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" ng-if="bankreconciliation.reconciliationtype == 'Bank file upload'">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <p>Please ensure that you have copied the selected file to the designated folder prior to uploading the bank file.</p>
                    <input type="file" style="width: 100%; height: 35px; border: none !important; cursor: pointer" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().file_changed(this)" ng-model="bankfilepath" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

Can anyone shed any light on how I can get this working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your submit button, `ng-disabled` attribute

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <select name="selectedbankaccountname" ng-options="choice for choice in bankaccountnames" ng-model="selectedbankaccountname" class="form-control" style="width:100% !important" focus-on="setfocus" required>
      <option></option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <!-- TODO - BUTTON NEEDS TO BE DISABLED IF BANK UPLOAD SELECTED & FILE NOT SELECTED -->
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="!bankfilepath  || startautoreconciliation.selectedbankaccountname.$invalid || disablebutton" ng-click="startrec()" title="Click to start the auto reconciliation procedure.">Start Auto Rec</button>
</div>
<div class="form-group" ng-if="bankreconciliation.reconciliationtype == 'Bank file upload'">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <p>Please ensure that you have copied the selected file to the designated folder prior to uploading the bank file.</p>
    <input type="file" style="width: 100%; height: 35px; border: none !important; cursor: pointer" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().file_changed(this)" ng-model="bankfilepath" />
  </div>
</div>
```

```
ng-disabled="!bankfilepath  || startautoreconciliation.selectedbankaccountname.$invalid || disablebutton"
```

check for `bankfilepath` as well.

So the button will be enabled only if the file is selected. Initially the `bankfilepath` will be undefined and once the user has selected a file, it will have the file path.

Comment: Thanks this works great for my new upload option but now has made the button disabled for all my other options which don't require an upload path.  Is there a way of doing this or would I need to create/create 2 submit button and show the relevant one depending on the selection from the drop down list

Comment: Managed to sort it doing: ng-disabled="bankreconciliation.reconciliationtype == 'Bank file upload' && !bankfilepath || startautoreconciliation.selectedbankaccountname.$invalid || disablebutton"